# Проблема с respond.js в ie8

Tags: responsive, media-queries, javascript, internet-explorer

Подключаю в <head>:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/respond.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/media-queries.css" />
```

В ие8 не подключается. Выдает:

> отказано в доступе
> respond.min.js
> код: 0

Уже и в конце документа подключал перед `</body>`, и заливал respond.min.js на ФТП и подключал от туда. Осел упорно не сдается (

Answer (score 1):

Из документации к respond.js:

> Due to security restrictions, some browsers may not allow this script to work on file:// urls (because it uses xmlHttpRequest). Run it on a web server.